# is possible to create a text with click action (like a Action link ) in blackberry mainscreen?

Tags: blackberry

This is seems like a pretty simple question. Is it possible to set a custom action for a text link (those blue texts that are underlined) inside mainscreen in blackberry. In other words, is it possible to have a handler do something on an event like feildchangelistner on the text?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the various fields that display text are children of the class [field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html)

As you can see from the doc you can override navigationClick, unclick. You may also set the font as one that is underlined and override the default color in paint. You will also need to code touch events if you are supporting the older touchscreen devices (Storms OS5 and below)

I would advise against doing any of this because RIM provide a class that seems to fit your exact needs in the advanced UI pack. Take a look at [HyperlinkButtonField](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)